# Finding the Fourier sine and cosine series of a function

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations

> Find the Fourier since and cosine series for $f(x) = x(l-x)$ on the interval $[0,l]$.

Attempted solution - The Fourier cosine series of an even function, $f(x)$ on $-l \leq x \leq l$ is given by 
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l} \right) \ \ \ \ \ A_n =  \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{l}\int_{0}^{l}f(x)dx \ \ \ \ &n = 0\\
\frac{2}{l}\int_{0}^{l}f(x)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l}dx \right) \ \ \ \ &n\neq 0
\end{cases}$$
Thus for $f(x) = x(l-x)$ on $[0,l]$ we have 
$$A_0 = \frac{1}{l}\int_{0}^{l}f(x)dx = \frac{1}{l}\int_{0}^{l}x(l-x)dx = \frac{l^2}{6}$$
$$A_n = \frac{2}{l}\int_{0}^{l}f(x)\cos\left(\frac{n \pi x}{l} \right)dx = \frac{2}{l}\int_{0}^{l}x(l-x)\cos\left(\frac{n \pi x}{l} \right)dx = -\frac{2l^2(n\pi - 2\sin(n\pi) + n\pi \cos(n\pi))}{n^3 \pi^3}$$
The Fourier cosine series is then 
\begin{align*}
x(l-x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n \cos\left(\frac{n \pi x}{l} \right) &= A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos\left(\frac{n \pi x}{l} \right)\\
&= \frac{l^2}{6} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2l^2(n\pi - 2\sin(n\pi) + n\pi \cos(n\pi))}{n^3 \pi^3}
\end{align*}
The Fourier series of an odd function $f(x)$ on $-l\leq x \leq l$ is given by 
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l} \right) \ \ \ \ \ B_n &= \frac{1}{l}\int_{-l}^{l}f(x)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l} \right)dx \ \ \ n = 1,2,3,\ldots\\
&= \frac{2}{l}\int_{0}^{l}f(x)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l} \right)dx \ \ \ n = 1,2,3,\ldots
\end{align*}
Thus for $f(x) = x(l-x)$ on $[0,l]$ we have 
$$B_n = \frac{2}{l}\int_{0}^{l}f(x)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l} \right)dx = \frac{2}{l}\int_{0}^{l}x(l-x)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l} \right)dx = -\frac{2l^2(n\pi\sin(n\pi) + 2\cos(n\pi) - 2)}{n^3 \pi^3}$$
Thus the Fourier sine series is then
$$x(l-x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l} \right) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2l^2(n\pi\sin(n\pi) + 2\cos(n\pi) - 2)}{n^3 \pi^3}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l} \right)$$

I am not sure if this is correct or not. Any suggestions or comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you use $\sin(n\pi) = 0$ for $n$ being an integer and $\cos(n \pi) -1 = (-1)^{n} - 1$ then the series can be reduced because even $n$ yields a zero.